# Let's suppose I am to display the letter R on mirror as well water , will I get the same images?

Tags: optics, reflection, refraction, geometric-optics

As far as my practical experience goes both look quiet the same when an image of any object is formed on them, yet I wanted to be ascertained is there any actual visible differences between both the images since mirror works on reflection only but water does both reflection and refraction too(I guess refraction here has no role) , I tried googling it but I didn't find any satisfying answers.

So basically my question is what's the difference between mirror image and a water image ?

Answer (score 0):

The images will be the same in both cases. However, the brightness and visibility of the images will greatly differ.

In the mirror, the backside is silvered and hence there is no absorption of light. The entire light falling on the mirror is reflected and so the image appears clear and bright.

However in case of a water image, the  light is partially absorbed and transmitted and thus the entire light falling on the mirror is not reflected. So the image appears a little dull.

Moreover the water surface being in dynamic equilibrium, ripples and the curved water surface may distort the image formed to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember from my experimental physics days, water has somewhat the same imaging properties as what a lens would, and the lens performs a Fourier transform on the image. However the water 'weakly' transforms compared to an actual lens so you don't tend to see much of a difference.